# Multiple click listeners are being added to the same html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Then in javascript I set a click listener in the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sub').click(function (event) {
        //do something
    });
});
```

Later on I dynamically add more .class elements so my html looks like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>

    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

And I add the click listeners again:

```
function addListeners(){
  $('.sub').click(function (event) {
        //do something
    });
}
```

Now the first four .sub elements have two click handlers attached and they fire twice when clicked.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delegate the event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').on('click', '.sub', function(event) {
        //do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Indeed, this is what delegation is for

Comment: delegation it is. @jose-calderon this is not what you asked for, but this is what you should do in such cases. delegation attaches event handler to all items under the provided root element, even the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `On()` instead of `click()` here in this case.So , your code gets

```
function addListeners(){
  $('#container').on('click','.sub',function (event) {
        //do something
    });
}
```

**The difference between `.on()` and `.click()`** would be that `.click()` may not work when the DOM elements associated with the `.click()` event are added dynamically at a later point while `.on()` can be used in situations where the DOM elements associated with the `.on()` call may be generated dynamically at a later point.

Comment: `on` != "delegation". It is possible to use `on` but not delegate.

Comment: Most of the answer still seems to imply `on` = delegation.